# UK Tourist Visa Refusal - Advice for Supporting Documents

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, tourist-visas

Just looking for a bit of advice here.

My girlfriend recently applied and was refused for a tourist (6 month) visitor visa for the UK. She is of Uzbek nationality but is currently living and studying in Lithuania on a temporary residence permit.

She is going to reapply as soon as possible as we were planning to spend summer here together before she was to return for her studies. I am a British citizen by the way.

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions of supporting documents that should be added this time round when applying that would help strengthen her case.

It seems to me that they do not believe we are together, so would including previous travel tickets, photographs together and a flat contract demonstrating that we have actually lived together help (we lived together in Cyprus for 3 months)?

Last time I included a written and signed letter of declaration stating that she would be staying with me, a copy of a bank statement as proof of address and a photocopy of my drivers licence. Included was also a letter indicating she would be returning for her next study year from her university.

Any help on the situation would be greatly appreciated so that we can rebook the flights as soon as possible.

I've attached the letter she was sent back below as well.

Thanks! [image]

[image]

Comment: There's really nothing unique about your girlfriends case where she was refused under (a)+(c)+(e). The part where they don't believe the ties you have together is just the icing on the case. In reality the meat of the matter is they don't believe she won't abscond, basically the ties pulling her to the UK are stronger than that to her home location. Be careful applying immediately again, chances are it **won't end well**. (a)+(c)+(e) is about as bad as it gets before spiraling into serial refusals.